# Heap objects don’t naturally support copy semantics

Tags: c++, copy, heap-memory, semantics

What is the meaning of **Heap objects don’t naturally support copy semantics** in C++. I found this while reading the CPP FAQ https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/csharp-java#universal-object but could not understand the meaning and applicability to C++.

Comment: IMO that is a nonsense sentence that should be disregarded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int a = 10;
int b = a;
```

In this above case, the value of `a` is copied to `b`. But consider,

```
int* c = new int(10);
int* d = c;
```

In this case, data is not copied but both the pointers point to same address.
If you delete `c`, then `d` points to invalid memory. In order to avoid this,
you need to allocate memory for d separately and then copy the data.

```
int* c = new int(10);
int* d = new int(*c);
```

When you have a class that has pointers, then you should make sure you define
copy-constructor and assignment operator and then handle the copy of data similar to the way I showed below.

For eg.,

```
class A
{
    private:
     int* m_data;

    public:

      A() : m_data(NULL) { }
      A(int x) : m_data(new int(x)) { }
      ~A() { delete m_data; }

      // Failing to provide the below 2 functions will 
      // result in shallow copy of pointers 
      // and results in double delete of pointers.
      A(const A& other) : m_data(new int(*(other.m_data)) { }
      A& operator=(const A& other)
      {
           A temp (other);
            std::swap (m_data, temp.m_data);
           return *this;
      }
};
```

Comment: Ya thanks I got it , its the difference between `shallow copy` and `deep copy` but could you help me understand the comparison with Java.